# Turkish character problem in post data

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have two applications running on diffrent servers with diffrent DB's. I need to post some data from one to another, so ,i use post method. I concatenate related info into a string, then POST it...
My data is something like:

```
26AU223/AHMET DEMİROĞLU/18439586958/0//2000-07-31/2000-06-11/42.00/0
```

For turkish characters, i try to use

```
var1 = '26AU223/AHMET DEMİROĞLU/18439586958/0//2000-07-31/2000-06-11/42.00/0'
var1.encode('iso8859_9')
```

but when i receive this data on the second application and decode it, i realize that Turkish characters can not be decoded correctly, so my result is :

```
26AU223/AHMET DEMï¿½Oï¿½U/18439586958/0//2011-07-31/2008-06-11/42.00/0
```

So **İ** and **Ğ** causes problem, and also following first letters **R** and **L** are mis-decoded too.

I tried diffrent encoding parameters for turish, also tries to POST daha without encode/decode (both applications use UTF-8) but i get a similar encoding error, with a strange � instead of **İR** and **ĞL** .

Comment: did you try utf8 encoding ? (just to get it clear)

Comment: I am using 2.6.5 and yes, i also give it a try without success.

Comment: did you try urlencoding the string ? (http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem with the easiest possible way (:

before **quote** my text, i cast it to string :

```
quote(str(var1))
```

And on the other side, unquote it in a similar way:

```
unquote(str(var1))
```

That solve the problem

Comment: Your solution won't help you if you don't understand what it does. According to your question, you already have a (bytes) string.

Comment: casting string before unquote might be useless, but quoting a __string__ is a need, since i use # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in each py file,unicode may cause trouble in some cases...

Comment: I am saying that your `var1` is already a string (= byte string in Python 2.x), so if your source file encoding is `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, the that variable is already UTF-8 encoded. You are not casting to string because it already *is* a string, so I wonder what you changed in your code to correct the behavior.

Comment: I just change that. But as far as i know, using a file encoding causes some problems, like when i wish to create a model filter and give a dict to it as: a = {'key':val} Model.objects.filter(**a) any dictionary key that is not parsed to string causes error. SO i have tou use a = {str('key'): val} to aviod that (:

Answer (score 1):

With Python 2.x, this is obviously wrong:

```
var1 = '26AU223/AHMET DEMİROĞLU/18439586958/0//2000-07-31/2000-06-11/42.00/0'
var1.encode('iso8859_9')
```

Python 2 has a bad design flaw in that it allows you to `.encode()` byte strings (`str` type). You must have a Unicode string, and then encode that before POSTing it. And using encodings other than UTF-8 is not reasonable.

```
var1 = u'26AU223/AHMET DEMİROĞLU/18439586958/0//2000-07-31/2000-06-11/42.00/0'
buf = var1.encode('utf-8')
# ...send buf over the network...
assert buf.decode('utf-8') == var1
```

And if you're constructing the POST data yourself, don't forget to do URL escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting a Unicode string object on the remote side? In that case, your problem is that the code responsible for reading the HTTP message body assumes a wrong character set. Set the HTTP request Content-Type header to 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-9'.

Comment: Oh thanks, the other Latin-1 things didnt work, only this worked (aka Latin 5)